# excel input the latest value based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want a formula that will insert the latest money earned by employee based on the newest date, so its something like this:

1. search for the newest date
2. see if the employee id matches the employee id
3. index the money earned in the newest date

[image]

Can anyone please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this array formula

[image]

```
=INDEX(B2:B12,MATCH(MAX(IF(A2:A12=E2,C2:C12,0)),IF(A2:A12=E2,C2:C12),0))
```

after entering the formula press Ctrl+Shift+Enter